# How to stop the h1 tag from changing the position of column

Tags: html, css

I've been looking all over for an answer to this but I can't find a fix anywhere. I'm just trying to move the h1 tag right over top of the icons but whenever I use margin-top or padding-top to move the h1 down the page it moves the column down as well. I put borders around all of the columns around there to see if maybe the borders were touching but that was no help. Is there like some sort of default padding around h1's or columns that you can't see?

Here is a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/4eller/pen/eVmxeM

HTML:

```
<hr width="35%">

<div class="container maincon2">
    <h1 class="wwd">Social Media Has Never Been Easier</h1>
    <hr class="hr1">
    <h1 class="whatwedo">What makes us stand out from the rest</h1>
    <div class="row topicons">
        <div class="col-md-4 maintab1">
            <img src="images/graph.png" class="barimg">
            <hr width="50%" id="hr2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 maintab2">
            <img src="images/piggy-bank.png" class="pigimg">
            <hr width="50%" id="hr2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 maintab3">
            <img src="images/support.png" class="supportimg">
            <hr width="50%" id="hr2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="container maincon3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mediumcon2">
            <hr class="hrgreen">
```

CSS:

```
.maincon2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #424242;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

.topicons {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 70px;
    height: 250px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Your `<h1>` tags appear to **already** be directly over the icons (with a bit of vertical space); both the header and icons are aligned to the hard left. Can you please update your question to showcase a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including frameworks), clearing stating **exactly** what the desired output should be? It looks like you're using Bootstrap, but even when including that, I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you put your code in something like jsfiddle so we could easily see it & modify it.

Comment: I put it in to codepen, my bad. Hopefully that better displays it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want (not really 100% clear),  you can apply `position: relative` to that tag and use `top` to move it down without affecting anything else, since `position: relative` plus position settings cause an element to be moved in relation to its original (static) position, but elements before and after it will remain were they are:

```
h1.whatwedo {
  position: relative;
  top:30px;
}
```

Changed codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQYRKY

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to do. Thank you, I just didn't know how to explain it properly.

Comment: BTW: An alternative would be to change the margins of that `h1`:  More top margin, less bottom margin, but for that you have to check the default margins first.

Answer (score -1):

Give the `h1` tag `position:absolute;` and then move it left with `left:200px`(replace 200 with whatever number you want)

The reason why when using `margin`, `padding` or `position:relative`, it will move other elements, is because then they are considered part of the "flow" of the page, meaning they will interact with and bump other elements around. `position:absolute`, removes the target element from the flow of the page, thus allowing you to put it wherever without moving other elements.

Comment: When people down vote, it would be helpful to the user if they noted why.